# Error connecting with SQL Server in Power BI

Tags: sql-server, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to connect to a database using the SQL Services Analysis database in Power BI and getting this error

> AnalysisServices: A connection cannot be made to redirector. Ensure that 'SQL Browser' service is running.

Both SQL server and Power BI are hosted on my laptop.

The database is available at https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/wide-world-importers-v1.0

I expect the database to be connected successfully

Comment: Do you mean in Power BI Desktop? Or on a Power BI + Reporting services?

Comment: Power BI Desktop. Release: August 2019

Product Version:
2.72.5556.801 (19.08) (x64)

Comment: Is your SQL Server set to listen to the default port?

Comment: Check in :  SQL Server Configuration Manager-> Sql Server Services -> SQL Server Browser is running

Comment: SQL Server installs several services that can be turned off and on independently, e.g.: SQL Server Agent, SQL Server Analysis Services, SQL Server Browser, SQL Server FullText Search, SQL Server Integration Services, SQL Server Reporting Services and finally SQL Server itself. As @GiovaniSalazar said, go to SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Services and check that the SQL Browser service is enabled and running.

Comment: SQL Server, SQL Server Agent and SQL Server Browser services are running. I cant still connect. I am seeing the same error that I posted in the question above.